# Is that a typo in extended linear predictor equation in Tutz & Schmid (2016)?

Tags: survival, splines

I am reading Tutz & Schmid ["Modeling Discrete Time-to-Event Data"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-28158-2) (2016) section 5.1 Smooth Baseline Hazard. On p. 109 they discuss estimation of models containing basis functions. The number of basis functions is $m$. Should $\phi_q$ not be $\phi_m$ in the last equation? ($q$ is the number of time periods for which we observe the individuals.)

[image]

Comment: Based on the given information only without having read the rest of the book, I tend to agree with you.

Comment: @ChristianHennig, thank you. The book seems to lack a bit of polish, but since I am new to the topic, I often hesitate to make the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suspect equation is a generalized notation for equation $(5.4)$. In $(5.4)$ the $\phi_s$ terms appear, where the index $s$ runs from $1...m$. It is without doubt that $\phi_q$ should be $\phi_m$, as a matter of micro-consistency in notation.